# Custom loop not working in singular.php, working in other pages

Tags: loop, pagination

I have a custom loop showing all the posts of my site that I want to display at the bottom of all post pages. Here's the loop:

```
function show_all_posts() {

    $ppp = 8;
    $page = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
        'post__not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts'), 
        'paged' => $page
    );

    $All = new WP_Query($args); 

    echo '<section class="posts infinite-container">
            <h3 class="legend">Keep Looking...</h3>';
                split_posts($All, true);

}
```

The loop is working initially, but when it's time to call the next posts (with infinite loading), nothing comes up. I have all sorts of other similar loops on the site, and they're all working, infinite loading included. The only difference I can think of is this particular one is used on the post pages (for which I'm using singular.php), while the others are on the homepage and archive pages. In fact, when I use the show_all_posts() function in the homepage, it works just fine!

Here's the split_posts function I wrote, in case that helps:

```
function split_posts($Query, $infinite = false) {

    $temp_query = $wp_query;
    $wp_query   = NULL;
    $wp_query   = $Query;

    if ($Query->have_posts()) : 

        $i = 1;     
        while ($Query->have_posts()) : $Query->the_post(); 

            if ($i % 4 == 1) :
                if ($infinite) echo '<div class="pRow infinite-item">';
                else echo '<div class="pRow">';
            endif;      

            $ID = get_the_ID();
            post_template($ID);

            if ($i % 4 == 0) echo '</div>';

        $i++;
        endwhile;

        if ($infinite) :        
            echo '</section>
                  <p class="infinite-more-link-wrap">'; 
                    next_posts_link('More...', $Query->max_num_pages); 
            echo '</p>';
        endif; 

    else : 

        no_posts_error();

    endif; wp_reset_postdata();

    $wp_query = NULL;
    $wp_query = $temp_query;

}
```

I guess for some reason, the max_num_pages call fails to see there's more posts. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look at the source for `next_posts_link`, it won't output anything on singular pages, it is intended for archives.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity's sake, it was enough to call the global $wp_query variable right at the top of the split_posts() function, like this:

```
function split_posts($Query, $infinite = false) {

    global $wp_query;
    $temp_query = $wp_query;
    $wp_query   = NULL;
    $wp_query   = $Query;

    ...

}
```

Cheers!